# How to build without filenamehashing in VueCli

Tags: vue.js, vue-cli-3

I would like to build my app and export files without random numbers, like `app.e48201ef.js` but app.js.

My app is in a /app/ folder at the root of a Wordpress, and I'm including the js files one by one in a template, to act on a .

Problem is I'm really confused by webpack, vue.config.js, the fact that Webpack is now included with VueCLi3, and I get the files included in a index.html, which I don't use.

How can I set a static name for each file in order to keep my app updated in production ?

Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should set `filenameHashing: false` in the `vue.config.js`, as suggested for exactly your case in the [docs](https://cli.vuejs.org/config/#filenamehashing).

```
module.exports = {
  filenameHashing: false
}
```

Comment: great you saved my time...i was looking for exact solution. thanks. @Giovane